# How to resize a picture both in Y axis and X axis CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to display a set of pictures in HTML. Since I am new to the topic. Now what I want to do is resizing the pictures based on the current window size but keep the aspect ratio. I tried many ways like width: auto and height: auto. All of them did not work properly. Best thing I could manage is to change the picture size on the x-axis. But it always cuts away the pictures on the Y-Axis. I want to make sure that the whole content is on the window size at any given time. Also i want to make sure that 5 pictures are besides each other.

```css
.image {
  position: top-left;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 19%;
  width: 19%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet I made you seems to work as exepcted

Comment: `position: top-left;` is not a thing. Position is relative, absolute, fixed etc.

Comment: @mplungjan i tried to run it but i run into the same issue as mentioned above. X-Axis wise it works perfectly fine. but on the Y axis it just cuts the pictures off instead of resizing. Is there maybe a issue with my browser? I run it on chrome and edge. which seems odd

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to see the entire, uncropped, image. So you'd want to avoid the `object-fit` property. Without `object-fit`, surely setting an explicit width and then setting `height: auto;` would give you want you want?

Comment: I am testing in Chrome. It does not chop anything

Comment: @mplungjan so the issue is on my end. not code wise. thanks for looking over it i try to figure out where my setting is breaking it

Comment: @NicolasGoosen I tried that take aswell. It doesn't seem to change anything. I set the fixed width but the cutt of if i only move the Y-axis is still present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grid` and a max-height with `vh` and max-width with `vw` for any item based on the number of elements:

```css
#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: max-content;
}
.image {
    max-width: 20vw;
    max-height: 33.33vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.lkz.de/cms_media/module_img/2197/1098748_2_detailbig_5f52b830aced9.jpg">
</div>
```

**When screen size is wide:**

[image]

**When axis-Y shrinks:**

[image]